# I want to my computer to be perceived by the iphone as an external keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to my computer to be perceived by the iphone as an external keyboard. For example, I connect an iphone to a computer via a lightning cable and run the Pages on the Iphone and my computer starts sending text via the lightning cable and this text is displayed in the pages. The question. What can I read about it?

Answer (score 1):

Already answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4437/can-i-use-a-pc-mac-keyboard-as-a-bluetooth-keyboard-for-iphone).

What you are looking for is to use your Mac/PC keyboard for inputing text in your iOS devices, which is pretty reasonable since iPhone’s relative small screen doesn’t make for a great keyboard.

This can be done and there are quite a few apps to achieve what you want. You download the app in your PC/MAC and they all work by presenting the hardware keyboard as Bluetooth keyboards, then the iOS device seamlessly connects to it. For example http://www.acrosscenter.com/ or https://www.houdah.com/type2Phone/.